# AjaxFileUpload - hiding upload button

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using AjaxFileUpload .Net4, is there any properties/methods to hide the upload button of FileUpload controls, because i am using multiple FileUpload controls and want to upload all file in a single button click

Comment: Do you mean `AsyncFileUpload`?

Comment: no AsyncFileUpload, AjaxFileUpload itself

Comment: Why are you using multiple controls?

Answer (score 1):

add style to your page

```
    <style>
    .ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton{
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
```